# How to set up a color palette in Blender?

Tags: modeling, materials, color

There is a youtuber named Imphenzia, who does speed model challenges. He has it set up in a way that lets him select a color and apply it to selected faces. That would make my modeling so much easier. Does anyone know a way to set this up?

Example is [this YouTube video (Timestamp 3:52)](https://youtu.be/YqYTg4YUxP4?t=232).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found an answer. Skip to 25:13 of [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HLMmaQM8Pg&list=PLC7nmYI-cbT0uJ8gghbk9LgT3p8uOzY54&index=4)

Comment: That is simply an Atlas Texture with different colors, and he scales faces UVs all the way to 0 so it's basically a point in 2D space, then he moves that point to the desired color swatch. That's one way of doing it, what is nice is you can use this texture in other softwares like a game engine and it will recognize the colors since it's based on UVs

Comment: @RowanMcAlpin Oh good, you found something. He also has a video where he explains the setup for his 10 minute modeling challenges, I think he says something about the color palette in there as well.

Comment: Yeah I found it and posted an answer.

Comment: Imphenzia uses 2 colour palettes. He explains it [here](https://youtu.be/_HLMmaQM8Pg?t=1514) - [8 bit](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5olic38j8fopet/ImphenziaPalette01.png?dl=0) - [16 bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMzwb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer: Create a 5x5 pixel image, and fill each pixel with a color you want to use.

Then open the shader editor.

Then, Shift+A, S for search, then type image texture.

Connect the image texture 'color' output to the 'base color' input of the Principled BSDF node.

Then, open the UV editor, and in the dropdown select your palette image.

Scroll up to zoom in to your image.

Then, tab into edit mode on your object, hover over the UV editor, then press A, S, 0.

Now, your faces should be tiny in the UV editor.

When you want to change the color of a face or multiple faces, you can select any faces in the 3D view, hover over the UV editor, and press 'G' to grab the faces and move them onto any of the colors in your palette.

[Source](https://youtu.be/_HLMmaQM8Pg?list=PLC7nmYI-cbT0uJ8gghbk9LgT3p8uOzY54&t=1513)

Comment: Actually, Imphenzia scales his UVs to 0.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after I posted this answer.